# git log get range of commits starting with a tag

Tags: git

I want to use git log to get a list of changes starting with a tag and going back, say 6 commits

```
git log --format="%h %ad %d %an: %s" --tags -n 6 --date=short
```

this will give me the last 6 commits, but ideally I would like to get a range that is in the past;
given the following

```
            x---y(tag101)---z---branch
           /
aa---bb---a---b---c---d---e---f---g(tag102)---h---HEAD
```

is it possible to get logs for tag101 and back 6 commits

```
y(tag101)
x
a
bb
aa
```

or for tag102

```
g(tag102)
f
e
d
c
b
```

most of the time when I am trying to get this information I am actually checkout on a tag and in detached HEAD state

I've tried a few different things, such as

```
git log tags/tag101..96c06be --format="%h %ad %d %an: %s" --tags -n 6 --date=short
```

this just seems to return commits starting from the last one made, ignoring the specified tag

Comment: I'm not sure what you think `--tags` does, but what it actually does is pretend you put *all* tags there, i.e. uses all of them as starting points.

Comment: you are right, removing `--tags` was key, i thought it was required to show the tag in the output; not the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git log --first-parent --oneline -n 6 yourtag`, modified to suit your needs. From the [Git log manual](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-log.html):

> --first-parent
>
> Follow only the first parent commit upon seeing a merge commit. This option can give a better overview when viewing the evolution of a particular topic branch, because merges into a topic branch tend to be only about adjusting to updated upstream from time to time, and this option allows you to ignore the individual commits brought in to your history by such a merge.

Comment: There is no need for first parent here. Also `-6` is good enough for specifying the number of commits.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able just to

```
git log -6 <tag name>
```

Then add any other qualifiers you want.